# What happens with iphone google analytics calls when there's no internet connection?

Tags: iphone, ios, google-analytics

Hey Fellow  Developers!
I'm doing a little research about Analytics products for iphone apps. I came across google analytics which seems pretty good. Somehow I'm not finding lot's of documentation about it. Basically my concern is:

What happens to a trackPageview or event tracking call when there's no Internet connection? 
Are these method calls persisted for future dispatch when there's a connection available or do they generate an error and that's it?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GA SDK has batching possibility, which is als recommended to use.

"To save on connection and battery overhead, we recommend batching your tracking requests. You can call dispatch on the tracking object any time you want to make a batch request, and you can do this either manually or at specific time intervals."

http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/mobile/analytics/docs/iphone/

Comment: Yes, exactly but what happens when batching fails to reach an internet connection?

In "know issues" states: "Possible inaccurate timestamps: timestamps are recorded at the time the application dispatches to Google Analytics, so if a user experiences long periods of offline use, the timestamps may not be 100% accurate."

Is this implying that tracking events are being stored somewhere to be sent later on?

Comment: yes, tacking data is stored for later sending. it is up to the developer, to initiate the batched send. You can check upfront, if internet connection (or other access) is available and then send. In worst case you lose some tracking data, which shouldn't be dramatic in relation to statistical analytics.

Comment: What do you mean by "In worst case you lose some tracking data, which shouldn't be dramatic in relation to statistical analytics.".

Analytics datas integrity are very important for me, do you have any exemple of "losing data situation" ?

Thanks

Comment: @Franck It is a documented feature of GA. The framework does not cache all data for ever. It works like a buffer with a limited size. You'll lose some data for excatly this device, in case it has no access to internet. Dramatic situation in case it is your only customer, but if this is one out of thousends devices it is not critical loss off statistics data.

Comment: The link is daed. is batching something not present in V3 SDK?

Answer (score 6):

According to Google. Their documentation says

> If a user loses network access or quits your app while there are still
>   hits waiting to be dispatched, those hits are persisted in local
>   storage. They will be dispatched the next time your app is running and
>   dispatch is called.

You can read more about how disptaching takes place at:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v2/dispatch

Answer (score 0):

Some of the other services out there are very robust with their batching. Localytics (www.localytics.com) has a free library which is open source so you can see how they batch. If the connection isn't available then the data is stored on the device until the next session when there is a connection.

-- Henry