# iOS: does google analytics SDK caches all data for sending them later if no internet is available?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, google-analytics

Does google analytics SDK caches all data for sending them later if no Wifi is available? I guess everything is OK when iPhone/iPad is online (has internet available) then it sends all events data. But what about its functionality when the device has no internet connection? Do I have manually to check for internet connection (for example with apple reachability class) and maintain the data cache for later use myself?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Short answer: **yes**.

More details:

1. In case you use dispatch period greater than zero (let's say 15):

   - every 15 seconds GA tracker will try to dispatch events, AND
   - if no network connection is available, tracker will try to dispatch after another 15 seconds until success, AND
   - if it fails and you quit the app (it's **not** paused in the background), on next application session, tracker will try to dispatch your events again according to dispatch period.
2. In case you use dispatch period is equal to -1, which means you dispatch your events manually by calling `[[GANTracker sharedTracker] dispatch]`:

   - if you call `dispatch` but connection is not available, event will get cached, so next `dispatch` call will try to send cached events in a batch,
   - again, events are cached between application sessions.

The above also applies to a mix of above two cases: you use dispatch period > 0, but you decide to dispatch some events manually.

**Note:** I have no idea how much events/data can GA tracker cache before its' buffers get overwritten or go haywire.

**Some other tips for using GA:**

- if you're unsure about something, set option `dryRun` to YES and test
  your scenario. Also you can use some other account ID for testing
  without dry run.
- use `GANTrackerDelegate` methods to see if hits were dispatched.

Comment: For me surprisingly GA fails to report offline activities.

To verify, We tried to put iPad offline for 15 mins note down what hits should appear after bringing it back online in half and hour and it seems all data is lost. Whereas FLURRY had all data accurately dispatched. Any idea ?

Comment: @rohan-patel sorry no idea, it's been almost three years since I've stopped using GA on iOS and I believe its API change a lot in this time.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484748/what-happens-with-iphone-google-analytics-calls-when-theres-no-internet-connect) is a related question, basically you need to use batching. I think [Flurry](http://www.flurry.com/) analytics makes this aspect more transparent (you just log events and it takes care of everything).

Comment: Batching? I think SDK automatically send hits once get internet connection. the link given in that answer is dead. :/